# Angular CLI Typescript Compile on build

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Just for clarification, when using the angular cli and typescript, when I run the command: `ng build`. Does that compile all the ts files to js? I noticed the `"compileOnSave"` property in the `tsconfig.json` is set to false.

There shouldn't be anything I have to do to compile the typescript files, correct? When exactly are they compiled?

**I am not sure why my question got a down vote. It is a legitimate question and the Angular CLI documentation does not explicit answer it.

**UPDATE: Upon further review, I noticed that I was getting some TS Lint errors on the first project I was working on, which is when I noticed it wasn't compiling. I believe the fact that it was not compiling may be related to that. Upon initializing a new project via the CLI, I can see that the TypeScript files do compile when the `ng build` command is run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved - see question Update. If you are noticing that the `.ts` files are not compiling, check the output pane and make sure there are no errors being output (for instance, with ts lint)